# Postgres Backup in Ms Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, backup, postgresql-9.2

Is it possible to create a VBA (MS_Access 2010) routine to automatically create Postgres (9.2) backup/restore?

Comment: MS Access is not an obvious candidate for that sort of task, but it is doable. You can run a macro from a command line switch, and you can exit MS Access via a macro command.

Comment: I'm using MS Access as a frontend to postgres. I was thinking in something that can read all of my tables and generate a SQL script file in a way that I can use it to restores data. I just doesn't know if it's possible.

Comment: You can use the TransferDatabase command create CSV files. That is probably the way to go.